# Unexpected T_Variable MYSQL UPDATE VALUES WHERE AND

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update my table `"user"` column `"img1_name"`, where the column `"blogger_id"` equals to `$blogger_id` and `"hotel_id"` column equals to `$hotel_id`.

```
$sql = "UPDATE user (img1_name) VALUES ('".$img1_name."') 
        WHERE (blogger_id) = (".$blogger_id.") AND (hotel_id) = ("$hotel_id")";
```

But it shows error below

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in
>   /home3/sunangel/public_html/lib/functions/functions.php on line 1593

Can I know how should I edit the line such that it does its function?

Comment: That line with your query has numerous syntax errors. Both php and mysql.

Comment: Hi John, may i know what is the syntax error. I think the problem lies within the code after AND, when i remove "AND (hotel_id) = ("$hotel_id")", it's working well.

Comment: You're confusing `UPDATE` and `INSERT` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have gone parenthesis crazy and have wrong syntax for your `UPDATE` statement...

Try this:

```
$sql = <<<EOT
UPDATE user
SET img1_name = '{$img1_name}'
WHERE blogger_id = {$blogger_id}
AND hotel_id = {$hotel_id}
EOT;
```

See MySQL documentation for proper `UPDATE` syntax - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your assistance and pointing out that. It helps! :) However, after i updated the code, it shows "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND hotel_id =' at line 4" is it possible reason that my server sql version is not compatible?

Comment: @Architheutus Have you echoed out your entire SQL string to make sure that it looks correct?  Like perhaps you didn't populate the value for `$blogger_id` which is causing a malformed query string like `WHERE blogger_id = AND hotel_id`?

Comment: Hi Mike, blogger_id and hotel_id is not void. In table 'hotel_content' each value is one, and when the SQL queries is inserted both variable is point to 1 so that it update the row

Comment: Oh btw, I copied and pasted the line you gave me. I didn't change a single thing.:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET img1_name = '".$img1_name."' WHERE blogger_id = ".$blogger_id." AND hotel_id = " . $hotel_id;
```

Here is SQL UPDATE syntax :

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET column_name1 = "your_value",
    column_name2 = "another_value"
WHERE your_filter_column = "your_filter_value"
```

Comment: That still doesn't solve that fact that `UPDATE ... VALUES ...` is not valid UPDATE syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my answer 2 seconds later... Don't be so nervous. ;)